# Ограничение использования промокодов

Tags: sql, база-данных, laravel, yii2

Хочу реализовать так, чтобы пользователь мог вводить промокод только один раз в день.
Пробовал написать код сам, но, т.к. не разбираюсь в yii2, не получилось заставить работать.

```
$limit = PromocodeUse::query()->where('user_id', $r->user()->id)->andWhere('updated_at', date('Y-m-d'))->first();

if ($limit) {
            return [
                'type' => 'error',
                'message' => 'promo_end'
            ];
        }
```

Если есть запись о применении промо в текущую дату, то выводить ошибку.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как я себе вижу эту картину.

У вас должно быть 3 таблицы в бд:

- "пользователи"
- "промокоды"
- "использованные промокоды"

Таблица "пользователи" - предположим у вас стандартная таблица, в том виде в котором она поставляется в Yii2 (id, username и тд.).

Таблица "промокоды" - с полями: (id, code_name).

Таблица "использованные промокоды" - с полями: (user_id, promo_code_id, use_date).

Далее, к самой логике.

1. Пользователь вводит "промокод", и на бекенде идет проверка - существует ли вообще такой **промокод** в таблице "промокоды".
2. Если существует такой **промокод** - идет следующая проверка: если пользователь с таким-то **промокодом**, **пользовательским id**, и **датой** применял код.
   Если применял, то у нас будет запись в таблице "использованные промокоды". Если записи в таблице нет, переходим к шагу 3.
3. Делаем запись в таблицу "использованные промокоды" - что **пользователь с id** использовал **промокод с id**, и **датой**.

Пример реализации под Ваш код:

```html
public function checkPromoCode(Request $request)
{
    if (Auth::check()) {

        $user = Auth::user();

        $promo = $request->get('promocode');

        $promoCode = Promocode::query()->where('name', $promo)->first();

        if (!$promoCode) {
            return [
                'type' => 'error',
                'message' => 'Код не существует',
            ];
        }

        $is_used_today = PromocodeUse::query()
            ->where('user_id', '=', $user->id)
            ->whereDate('created_at', '=', Carbon::today())
            ->exists();

        if ($is_used_today) {
            return [
                'type' => 'error',
                'message' => 'Промокоды можно использовать 1 раз в сутки',
            ];
        }

        PromocodeUse::query()->create([
            'promocode_id' => $promoCode->id,
            'user_id' => $user->id,
        ]);

        $user->increment('balance', $promoCode->sum);

        return [
            'type' => 'success',
            'newBalance' => $user->balance,
            'message' => 'Промокод успешно применен!',
        ];

    } else {

        return [
            'type' => 'error',
            'message' => 'Ошибка в запросе',
        ];

    }
}
```